# Why are there never any disagreements about what date today is?

Tags: epistemology

Today is 8/20/2019. I know this because my computer says so. But when I was growing up, people did not have computers to tell us the date. Yet somehow, everyone agreed on what date it was. And this was given that there was not a single person in the world who was in charge of making sure we were counting the days of our calendars correctly. In fact, I do not know of any recorded instance in history where people disagreed about the date of year. (Note, I'm only talking about situations in which the people were all using the same calendars.)

This seems to be a miracle. With all of the arguments and disputes in the world and different opinions about lots of things, why have people always agreed about the answer to the question, "What is today's date?"?

Comment: First, the [International Earth Rotation and Reference Systems Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Earth_Rotation_and_Reference_Systems_Service) is "in charge" of it, and second, people often "agree" when they do not care one way or another. When it mattered for religion, they [did argue a lot](https://www.ancient-origins.net/history-important-events/new-year-old-calendar-origins-and-controversy-gregorian-calendar-005047) over Julian and Gregorian dates, and the Orthodox and Catholics still disagree when the "true" date of Easter and Christmas is. No miracles, I am afraid.

Comment: i downvoted, tho it seems churlish of me now. it was the use of 'miracle' haha

Comment: I appreciate the candidness @another_name. I personally find anonymous downvoters more despicable.  If OP (Feinstein) edits the question you should be able to reverse the downvote.

Comment: I hope my edits were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Cute question! But not quite true: there are dozens of calendars followed by millions of people.

(I am treating "date" as offset in calendar from the first day)

For example

- Muslim : strictly lunar
- North Indian : Lunar with an extra month added every 3 years as "correction"
- South Indian : Rigorously solar : month means 30 degrees of sun movement in the zodiac
- Etc etc. See [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars)

That said, yes it still is surprising: People are ready to kill each other over who is the messiah. But when my birthday is can be ambiguous and no one minds!